# Install Stackless without uninstalling Python

Tags: python-2.7, python-stackless

It seems like on Windows I have to uninstall Python before installing stackless (http://stackless.com/wiki/Download). I have Python 2.7 installed, a solution may be installing Stackless Python 3.2, but I will have to switch between Python 2 and 3 syntax. Is there anyway to install Stackless without uninstalling Python? Otherwise I'll loose all Python modules I've installed and the CPython interpreter.

Comment: Stackless is a replacement for CPython.

Comment: Yes, and? I still need to uninstall CPython first. That will remove all the modules I've installed. And that's why I'm asking for a method to keep both installed and also the same version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are binary snapshots which can be extracted over a standard Python installation, to turn it into a Stackless installation.  This would keep all your modules.  They are on the download page on the stackless web site.

However, the last time one of these was made, was for 2.7.2.

You could download the one for 2.7.2, look at what files are in it, download the Stackless installer for the standard Python version you are actually using and extract those same files, and put them into place manually.

Of course, if you really wanted an answer for this, you would ask on the Stackless mailing list.

Comment: Binary snapshots looks like a solution. I'll try that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Install Stackless into a local folder, install virtualenv using pip (in any implementation), and create an environment where the binary is Stackless.